# c# Data memory storage Sizeof, basestream.position and filestream.length are contradictory

Tags: c#, byte

```
string file = @"G:\test.dat";
        int  num = 12;
        char c = 'w';
        FileStream fsSave = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bwSave = new BinaryWriter(fsSave);
        Console.WriteLine("Start position:" + bwSave.BaseStream.Position);
        //bwSave.Write((int)num);
        bwSave.Write((char)c);
        Console.WriteLine("End position:" + bwSave.BaseStream.Position);
        bwSave.Flush();
        bwSave.Close();
        fsSave.Close();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Console.WriteLine("char:"+sizeof(char));
        Console.WriteLine("int:" + sizeof(int));
        Console.WriteLine("fs.Length:" + fs.Length);
        Console.ReadLine();
        br.Close();
        fs.Close();
I write a char type data or an int type data to a binary file, and then read them  
 into memory from the binary file to try to explore the number of bytes they store in memory.
When I write a char type data, the console output is:  
C#
Start position:0
End position:1
char:2
int:4
fs.Length:1
```

From the start position and end position displayed in [bwsave. Basestream. Position], we can know that a char data occupies 1 byte.
It can be known from [sizeof (char)] that a char type data occupies 2 bytes.
From [FS. Length], we can know that a char type data occupies 1 byte.
How many bytes does a char data occupy?

When I write only one int type data, the values displayed by [bwsave. Basestream. Position], [sizeof (char)] and [FS. Length] are consistent, and they all occupy 4 bytes.

Comment: If you wrote to the file with the same UTF16 encoding that .NET uses, then you would get the same size ([example](https://rextester.com/WPO75582)). Since `BinaryWriter` will be using UTF8 by default, you could use a character such as 水 for other interesting results ([example](https://rextester.com/XACFE11201)).

Comment: 对中文和英文字符的存储，有本质区别吧。您说的我还是不很理解，您能再指点下为什么对于单独英文字符， [FS. Length]与 [sizeof (char)]、[bwsave. Basestream. Position]相矛盾呢？

Comment: Please write in English on StackOverflow. In .NET, the way text (`string`) is stored in memory is using UTF16 encoding. UTF16 means that every character (`char`) takes up two bytes. Text encoding is how text is actually stored in memory, and the same character can be encoded differently depending on the encoding. UTF8 (default used by `BinaryWriter`) will use 1 character for English characters, 2, 3, or even 4 for other languages' characters.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses).

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, but I still don't understand why they are different. I think they both show the size of a character in memory in bytes. Since it is in memory, the encoding of the same character must be the same.

Comment: The file isn't in memory. The file is in the file.